# How would you authorize pushes only in certain directories with Gitolite-v3?

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

I have a working configuration for a symfony project:

```
@admin = admin ku
   @developer = sarhan dima_syrv sarhandom a_bobkov
   @testers = novikov_d 

   repo    dev
       - master = @admin @developer @testers
       RW+      =   @admin @developer
       RW+     =   jenkins ku
       RW      =   @testers
```

I want to make the group of testers could only write to folders Tests. I'm doing this configuration: @admin = admin ku @developer = sarhan dima_syrv sarhandom a_bobkov @testers = novikov_d

```
repo    dev
       - master = @admin @developer @testers
       RW      =   @admin @developer
       RW+     =   jenkins
       RW      =   @testers
       RW NAME/ =  @admin
       RW NAME/src =   @admin @developer
       RW NAME/src/.*/.*/Tests   =   @testers
```

I have a working configuration for a symfony project I want to make the group of testers could only write to folders Tests I'm doing this configuration And it gives me only part of the solution, testers can write only in Tests folder, but no one can push new branches can only record in the old branches. How to make everyone to create a new branch, while testers could only write to folders Tests? Please help me!